# Redirect DNS to another DNS

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have about 300 domains using my company DNS ns1.x.com.br and ns1.x.com.br

I want to use CloudFlare with all those 300 domains but when I add a domain to CloudFlare they give me new DNS that I need to change in my domains.

So far I added 70 domains to CloudFlare and they gave me only 3 sets of primary and slave DNS.

So, can I point my ns1.x.com.br to the primary DNS provided by CloudFlare? And do the same with the slave?

After that I will create a ns3.x.com.br and point it to another CloudFlare DNS. Will it work?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare works at the DNS level in this way:

1. You have to signup for CloudFlare and add the domain (make sure all of your DNS records are in your DNS zone file at CloudFlare).
2. You then change to our nameservers at the registrar.
3. Only our nameservers can be at the registrar.

"So, can I point my ns1.x.com.br to the primary DNS provided by CloudFlare? And do the same with the slave?

After that I will create a ns3.x.com.br and point it to another CloudFlare DNS. Will it work?"

These records should be in your CloudFlare DNS zone file for the site(s) on those nameservers. They can't be active at the registrar because only CloudFlare's nameservers can be there for our service to properly work.

Note: I'm not sure if you're providing commercial hosting for sites. If yes, you might want to look at becoming a [CloudFlare Hosting Partner](https://www.cloudflare.com/hosting-partners) instead (you don't have to worry about changing nameservers).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is a possibility to add domain in the new name server first you need to know the domain secret of each domain(It's a 6 Digit pin maintained with your current DNS)Theft Protection pin also needed. Both are same in the ResellerClub.

If you are using ResellerClub means Its Really easy to change, Because it has a Bulk Domain Booking option. That have a option "add existing Domain" option.
If You have any other Problem. Or this not a exact answer you need, Then please chat with me. I will update the answer. Thank You...